# tbb parallel_reduce for a snippet of OpenMP reduction

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp, intel, tbb

I have the following code snippet of OpenMP that I know works correctly for sure.

```
char cipherChar=plainText[charLoop];
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(^:cipherChar)
for(keyLoop=0;keyLoop<numKeys;keyLoop++) {
    cipherChar = cipherChar ^ getBit( &(keyList[keyLoop]), charLoop);
}
cypherText[charLoop]=cipherChar;
```

But when I try to write this code in tbb, I don't get the correct output

```
char cipherChar=plainText[charLoop];
cipherChar ^= tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, numKeys), cipherChar,
[&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r, char c) -> char {
            char result = c;
            for(int i = r.begin(); i <= r.end(); i++) {
                    result ^= getBit( &(keyList[i]), charLoop);
            }
            return result;
    },

    [](char a, char b) {
            return a ^ b;
    }
);
cypherText[charLoop]=cipherChar;
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong in the above tbb code that I am getting a wrong result?

Comment: `i <= r.end()` should be `i < r.end()`.

Comment: Strangely, I still get the same incorrect output after fixing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to `parallel_reduce` - the one following `blocked_range` - should be the identity value for the used reduction operation. This value is used by the implementation to initialize accumulators. For exclusive or, the identity value is 0. Also it is important that the type of the identity value matches the type of the result.

So, your call should be

```
cipherChar ^= tbb::parallel_reduce(
    tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, numKeys),
    char(0), // <- identity for XOR
    body_lambda,
    reduction_lambda
);
```